# Excel For Loop VBA Macro not working

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel spread sheet with 2 columns, with the last row being `287983`. In column A there's numbers, if a cell doesn't have a number `NaN` is placed there. In, column B there's dates. I'm trying to use the following macro to remove all rows where cells in column A have `NaN`:

```
Sub Rowdel()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 1) = "NaN" Then Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i
End Sub
```

However, when I run the above code, the `NaN` cells are still there. Can anyone suggest why the code isn't working?

Comment: Your code worked for me.  Do you need to qualify the Cells maybe with a Worksheet.  For example `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1)`?

Comment: This seems to work fine for me. One potential issue may be that your 'NaN' cell contains something other than 'NaN' (different capitalization, different underlying datatype, etc.). Try adding a `Debug.Print Cells(i, 1)` inside of you loop and verifying that what you get is indeed 'NaN'.

Comment: another suggestion is that the right Sheet is not active while running this code. This code will only look at the active sheet as it is now. So add a correct sheet reference `sheetx.Cells(i,...`

Comment: Assuming the problem isn't the sheet reference as already suggested, try `Trim(Lcase(Cells(i,1))) = "nan"`.  Or use `StrComp()`.   Sometimes string comparisons can be flakey.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that this code is referencing the correct Worksheet. You are probably running the code on the wrong worksheet, which contains no `NaN` in column A and thus leads to no deletions or other visible signs of the code running.

You could try to debug this code using the following (debug-only) version:

```
Sub Rowdel()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        Cells(i, 1).Select
        If Cells(i, 1) = "NaN" Then Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i
End Sub
```

From the Excel VBA window, execute the sub using <kbd>F8</kbd>, which will allow you to step through the code and check which worksheet you are referencing.